# Calculating a value

Tags: manipulate, variable

I'm trying to calculate the value of F12 and show the value of it on screen. But for some reason I keep getting Null as an output.

```
Manipulate[
With[{
k = 8.99*10^9,
r = 0.2,
c1 = Abs[x],
c2 = Abs[y],
F12 = k*c1*c2/((r)^2)
},
Print[F12]],
{x, -1, 1}, 
{y, -1, 1}
]
```

Comment: You can't nest definitions in `With` like that, e.g. `F12` depends on `k`, which is defined as one of the local variables in `With` along with `F12`, which means that `F12` will never see that value of `k`.

Comment: What functions(s) should I use to do it then?

Comment: I mean, @corey979 already has a perfectly respectable fix. I was just explaining why what you did can't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
With[{k = 8.99*10^9, r = 0.2},
 Manipulate[
  F12 = k*Abs[x]*Abs[y]/r^2,
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}
  ]
 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing `Null` because that is what `Print`, by design, should always return. Ordinarily `Print` would also make a cell with your expression printed in it, but this doesn't work inside `Manipulate` and your `Print` command output appears in the messages window instead. The highlighted bit in the messages window image included below is from running your code.

Another problem (highlighted by @march in the comments) is that some of the variables in `F12` are not defined properly. This is because `With` performs a direct replacement of symbols which are set in its first argument. So in your code `Manipulate` only sees (c1 c2 k)/r^2, where c1, c2, k, and r are not set.

Here is your code with a slight fix allowing `F12` to be defined in the second argument of `With`:

```
Manipulate[With[{k = 8.99*10^9, r = 0.2}, F12 = k*Abs[x]*Abs[y]/r^2];
           Print[F12], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Dynamic[F12]
(* 2.02275*10^11 *)
```

[image]